# Magento 2 : How to get subcategory details using main category url_key

Tags: magento2, category, category-attribute

I want to get the **subcategories** of a **main category** using its main categories `url_key` to the home page.

I tried in this way.

```
<?php 
namespace Eightmedia\Homepage\Block\Index;

class Index extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template {


protected $_categoryFactory;

public function __construct(
\Magento\Catalog\Model\CategoryFactory $categoryFactory,
\Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\Context $context,
array $data = []) {
    $this->_categoryFactory = $categoryFactory;
    $this->_storeConfig = $scopeConfig;
    $this->_registry = $registry;
    parent::__construct($context, $data);

}

public function getSubcategoryByUrlkey($url_key)
{ 
        $categorys = $this->_categoryFactory->create()
                          ->getCollection()
                          ->addAttributeToFilter('url_key',$url_key)
                          ->addAttributeToSelect('*');
        $cat_id = $categorys->getFirstItem()->getEntityId();

        $category = $this->_categoryFactory->create()->load($cat_id);
        $childrenCategories = $category->getChildrenCategories();

        foreach($childrenCategories as $subcategorie) {
           echo '+'.$subcategorie->getName().
                '+'.$subcategorie->getDescription().
                '+'.$subcategorie->getData('featured_manufacturer').'</br>';
}
}
```

Here i can get the sub_category_name but i cannot get any other stuffs. **featured_manufacturer** is a custom category attribute.

Magento version 2.2.2

1 . **How to get all subcategories ?**

2 . **How to get custom category attribute values?**

**UPDATE : My install script**

```
$eavSetup -> removeAttribute(\Magento\Catalog\Model\Category::ENTITY, 'featured_manufacturer');


        $eavSetup -> addAttribute(\Magento\Catalog\Model\Category :: ENTITY, 'featured_manufacturer', [
                    'type' => 'int',
                    'label' => 'Featured Manufacturer?',
                    'input' => 'select',
                    'required' => false,
                    'source' => 'Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Source\Boolean',
                    'sort_order' => 110,
                    'global' => \Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\ScopedAttributeInterface::SCOPE_GLOBAL,
                    'group' => 'General Information',
                    "default" => "",
                    "class"    => "",
                    "note"       => ""
        ]
        );
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tested code it is working with following logic you can test it. you can add `->addAttributeToSelect('featured_manufacturer')`

```
public function getSubcategoryByUrlkey($url_key)
{ 
        $categorys = $this->_categoryFactory->create()
                          ->getCollection()
                          ->addAttributeToFilter('url_key',$url_key)
                          ->addAttributeToSelect('*');
        $cat_id = $categorys->getFirstItem()->getEntityId();

        $category = $this->_categoryFactory->create()->load($cat_id);
        $childrenCategories = $category->getChildrenCategories();
        $allChildIds = $childrenCategories->getAllIds();

        $newCollection = $this->_categoryCollectionFactory->create()
                        ->addFieldToFilter('entity_id',array('in' => $allChildIds))
                            ->addAttributeToSelect('*');
        foreach($newCollection as $subcategorie) {

           echo '+'.$subcategorie->getName().
                '+'.$subcategorie->getDescription().
                '+'.$subcategorie->getData('featured_manufacturer').'</br>';
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you create custom category attribute via InsallData/UpgradeData script? Here is the proper way of creating a custom attribute, check if below values are true else it won't retrieve on models

Proper way is to in the Install/Upgrade script:

```
 $eavSetup->addAttribute(
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\Category::ENTITY,
        'my_custom_attribute',
        [
            // ...
            'used_in_product_listing' => true, // for category pages
            'visible_on_front' => true, // for frontend??
            'is_used_in_grid' => true, // for category pages
            'is_visible_in_grid' => true // for category pages
        ]
    );
```

also on the collection do:

```
$collection->addAttributeToSelect('my_custom_attribute')
```

and if its the template you can just call:

```
$category->getMyCustomAttribute()
// or
$category->getData('my_custom_attribute');
```

Comment: yes.via a custom mmodule i created the custom category attribute.Please check my approach & help me to solve.to where i want to add the $collection->addAttributeToSelect('my_custom_attribute') in my subcategory foreach()?

Comment: Yes you are right. Try it!

Comment: i did not add 'used_in_product_listing' => true, // for category pages
            'visible_on_front' => true, // for frontend??
            'is_used_in_grid' => true, // for category pages
            'is_visible_in_grid' => true // for category pages in my install script.How can i upgrade it?